# add infowindow content to multiple select list onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add every marker's infowindow content to list using javascript.
I did it through dropdown menu. When I click each element from dropdown the it will be stored in list division. But, I want to do same thing in map infowindow content by onclick event.

I want to do same thing like this: http://odyniec.net/projects/selectlist/
but, instead of dropdown menu I have different infowindows on map.

What should I put in content to call function?

map infowindow:

```
var message = ["Ronak","Patel","Mark","Secret","Mission"];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<a onclick="$(\'select#name\').next()\
                   .find(\'option[value=&quot;\'+$(this).text()+\'&quot;]\')\
                   .trigger(\'click\');return false;" >'+message[num]+'</a>'
});
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('select#name').selectList({ sort: true });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div>
      <select id="name">
      <option value="?">?</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must trigger a click-event on the desired option.

Example that triggers a click on the option with the value "Ronak":

```
content: '<a onclick="$(\'select#name\').next()\
                       .find(\'option[value=&quot;\'+$(this).text()+\'&quot;]\')\
                       .trigger(\'click\');return false;" >Ronak</a>'
```

---

**Related to the comments:**

How to populate a select dynamic, e.g. by a given array:

```
var message = ["Ronak","Patel","Mark","Secret","Mission"];
$(document).ready(function () {
  //append an option for each array-item
  $.each(message,function(){$('<option/>').val(this).text(this)
                              .appendTo('select#name');})

  //initialize the selectList
  $('select#name').selectList({ sort: true });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks. But, What will be the jquery code to add those selected values in input text box? (as shown on this link: <http://odyniec.net/projects/selectlist/>)

Comment: The list will be populated via HTML, it's a `<select/>` with options, e.g. `<select id="name"><option value="Ronak">Ronak</option></select>`

Comment: It's working perfect. but 1 more question: What if the values are dynamic. I changed the above code. Thanks.

Comment: I've  added an example above